# Trying to get information from multiple gameObjects in a scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, singleton, collision-detection

Hope everybody who's reading this is having a great day!

Anyways I'm having a little bit of a problem with a system I want to implement in my Unity Project, basically it's a Enemy ID system. The idea was whenever the player enters in contact with a enemy, it would get it's ID and would use it to instantiate them in a battle scene.

This is the Scriptable Object I'm using as a template for the enemy stats and ID

[image]

This is a example of how would the enemy stats look like

[image]

And this is the script that check the collisions with the enemies
[image]

My problem stand from that I can only get information of one kind of enemy, I've tried making the enemy check the collisions so they would get their own ID, it worked but it would be hell to parse this information through scenes. Is there a way to make the script which check collision detect more than one type of enemy? Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: [**Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: What is `wormStats` and how is it realted to the `matoStats` class and the `enemyStats` you show us...?

Comment: Just a small heads-up. Do you notice those three little dots beneath the first letter of your class and method names? The editor's trying to tell you that you're using the wrong convention. Method and class names should be in PascalCase (like the OnTrigger event), while camelCase is typically reserved for variables.

Comment: And also i wouldn't use `ScriptableObject` like this ... why use an SO if then every instance of your class overwrites the values of possibly the **same** referenced SO? Makes little sense this way round ...

Comment: @derHugo Just don't mind the  `wormStats` I didn't take the right screenshot that's all, it should be `matoStats` which hold basically the same variables. As for the use of SO's in this way I'm just experimenting what will work best for the project that's all, I have other ways in mind on how to this differently.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave a comment, but my reputation isnt quiet high enough yet. Is there a reason you cant use raycasting? I believe you are only evaluating a single gameObject.

```
Enemy = collision.gameObject;
```

You then compare that single enemy object

```
if(Enemy.CompareTag("Enemy")) {

}
```

You should likely store an array of enemies and check each one on collision enter.